# Web usability: select from very large data

Tags: web, html-select, usability

On the project I joined, somewhere the user has to select a value (a person) from a very large set (average 1 000, can go up to 30 000).
The current solution is to ask for at least 3 letters of the {firstName lastName} string, and then populate a dropdown with all the matching people so there is a lot less to scroll before finding the right person.

I find it quite painful to use, are there other ways to handle selection from large data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery autocomplete plugins for these type of things. They can use async ajax request and json data type to process the data. It can provide fast response for user.

Comment: Thanks, I just saw jQuery automplete has everything I need: multiple values + remote data + caching. Awesome!